How can I determine the input voltage for running a DC motor?
I have a DC motor that has been on my bench for months.  I don't know where it came from.
What does it mean when a DC motor has this product number and specifications:

ZYT3424F-L94
DC110V
Its diameter is about 2 inches and the length is about 4 inches.
It is about 500 grams.

Does it mean 94 volt input voltage, or 110 input voltage?


I guess L94 is length 94 mm (about 4 inches).

I used google translate on the motor label image. The result is:

I.e. from the label the voltage is 110 V DC.
